# Why is the element order changing once a sorted list converted to a set in Python?

Tags: python, list, set

Why is the order changes when I convert the list to a set? How do I achieve a sorted set result in Python?

```
string = 'test'
result = sorted([character for character in string])
print(result)
```

```
#output
['e', 's', 't', 't']
```

```
print(set(result))
```

```
#output
{'t', 'e', 's'}
```

I am trying to produce this:

```
{'e', 's', 't'}
```

Comment: You can’t use a Set for this.

Comment: Joe, do you know how I could achieve that?

Comment: @RaminMelikov Check my answers

Comment: What’s your goal? Unique values? Something else?

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica I checked the answer but the answer produces a list and not a set.

Comment: @Joe I want to produce {'e', 's', 't'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

Here you should use:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
string = 'test'
result = sorted([character for character in string])
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(result)))
```

Or if your version >= 3.7, dictionaries are ordered, so you can use:

```
string = 'test'
result = sorted([character for character in string])
print(list(dict.fromkeys(result)))
```

Comment: But in both cases it produces a list and not a set.

Comment: @RaminMelikov If you want a set it will be impossible.